# Why ctags doesn't work for me?

Tags: ruby, vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I try to work with ctags and it simply doesn't work.

I follow this screencast : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4f3AENLrdYo. When I press Ctrl + ], it does not matter.

This is my .vimrc :

```
" vim:set ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab:

call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" BASIC EDITING CONFIGURATION
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
scriptencoding utf-8
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
set number
set nocompatible
" allow unsaved background buffers and remember marks/undo for them
set hidden
" remember more commands and search history
set history=10000
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set autoindent
set laststatus=2
set showmatch
set incsearch
set hlsearch
" make searches case-sensitive only if they contain upper-case characters
set ignorecase smartcase
" highlight current line
set cursorline
set cmdheight=2
set switchbuf=useopen
set numberwidth=5
set showtabline=2
set winwidth=85
set shell=bash
" Prevent Vim from clobbering the scrollback buffer. See
" http://www.shallowsky.com/linux/noaltscreen.html
set t_ti= t_te=
" keep more context when scrolling off the end of a buffer
set scrolloff=3
" Store temporary files in a central spot
set backup
set backupdir=~/.vim-tmp,~/.tmp,~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp
set directory=~/.vim-tmp,~/.tmp,~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp
" allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start
" display incomplete commands
set showcmd
" Enable highlighting for syntax
syntax on
" Enable file type detection.
" Use the default filetype settings, so that mail gets 'tw' set to 72,
" 'cindent' is on in C files, etc.
" Also load indent files, to automatically do language-dependent indenting.
filetype plugin indent on
" use emacs-style tab completion when selecting files, etc
set wildmode=longest,list
" make tab completion for files/buffers act like bash
set wildmenu
let mapleader=","
let g:ctrlp_max_height = 40

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" CUSTOM AUTOCMDS
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
augroup vimrcEx
  " Clear all autocmds in the group
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78
  " Jump to last cursor position unless it's invalid or in an event handler
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \   exe "normal g`\"" |
    \ endif

  "for ruby, autoindent with two spaces, always expand tabs
  autocmd FileType ruby,haml,eruby,yaml,html,javascript,sass,cucumber set ai sw=2 sts=2 et
  autocmd FileType python set sw=4 sts=4 et

  autocmd! BufRead,BufNewFile *.sass setfiletype sass 

  autocmd BufRead *.mkd  set ai formatoptions=tcroqn2 comments=n:&gt;
  autocmd BufRead *.markdown  set ai formatoptions=tcroqn2 comments=n:&gt;

  " Indent p tags
  autocmd FileType html,eruby if g:html_indent_tags !~ '\\|p\>' | let g:html_indent_tags .= '\|p\|li\|dt\|dd' | endif

  " Don't syntax highlight markdown because it's often wrong
  autocmd! FileType mkd setlocal syn=off
augroup END

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" COLOR
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
:set t_Co=256 " 256 colors
:set background=dark

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" STATUS LINE
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
:set statusline=%<%f\ (%{&ft})\ %-4(%m%)%=%-19(%3l,%02c%03V%)

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" MISC KEY MAPS
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
map <leader>y "*y
" Move around splits with <c-hjkl>
nnoremap <c-j> <c-w>j
nnoremap <c-k> <c-w>k
nnoremap <c-h> <c-w>h
nnoremap <c-l> <c-w>l
" Insert a hash rocket with <c-l>
imap <c-l> <space>=><space>
" Can't be bothered to understand ESC vs <c-c> in insert mode
imap <c-c> <esc>
" Clear the search buffer when hitting return
:nnoremap <CR> :nohlsearch<cr>
nnoremap <leader><leader> <c-^>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" ARROW KEYS ARE UNACCEPTABLE
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
map <Left> :echo "no!"<cr>
map <Right> :echo "no!"<cr>
map <Up> :echo "no!"<cr>
map <Down> :echo "no!"<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" MULTIPURPOSE TAB KEY
" Indent if we're at the beginning of a line. Else, do completion.
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! InsertTabWrapper()
    let col = col('.') - 1
    if !col || getline('.')[col - 1] !~ '\k'
        return "\<tab>"
    else
        return "\<c-p>"
    endif
endfunction
inoremap <tab> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper()<cr>
inoremap <s-tab> <c-n>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" OPEN FILES IN DIRECTORY OF CURRENT FILE
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
cnoremap %% <C-R>=expand('%:h').'/'<cr>
map <leader>e :edit %%
map <leader>v :view %%

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" RENAME CURRENT FILE
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! RenameFile()
    let old_name = expand('%')
    let new_name = input('New file name: ', expand('%'), 'file')
    if new_name != '' && new_name != old_name
        exec ':saveas ' . new_name
        exec ':silent !rm ' . old_name
        redraw!
    endif
endfunction
map <leader>n :call RenameFile()<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" PROMOTE VARIABLE TO RSPEC LET
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! PromoteToLet()
  :normal! dd
  " :exec '?^\s*it\>'
  :normal! P
  :.s/\(\w\+\) = \(.*\)$/let(:\1) { \2 }/
  :normal ==
endfunction
:command! PromoteToLet :call PromoteToLet()
:map <leader>p :PromoteToLet<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" EXTRACT VARIABLE (SKETCHY)
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! ExtractVariable()
    let name = input("Variable name: ")
    if name == ''
        return
    endif
    " Enter visual mode (not sure why this is needed since we're already in
    " visual mode anyway)
    normal! gv

    " Replace selected text with the variable name
    exec "normal c" . name
    " Define the variable on the line above
    exec "normal! O" . name . " = "
    " Paste the original selected text to be the variable value
    normal! $p
endfunction
vnoremap <leader>rv :call ExtractVariable()<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" INLINE VARIABLE (SKETCHY)
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! InlineVariable()
    " Copy the variable under the cursor into the 'a' register
    :let l:tmp_a = @a
    :normal "ayiw
    " Delete variable and equals sign
    :normal 2daW
    " Delete the expression into the 'b' register
    :let l:tmp_b = @b
    :normal "bd$
    " Delete the remnants of the line
    :normal dd
    " Go to the end of the previous line so we can start our search for the
    " usage of the variable to replace. Doing '0' instead of 'k$' doesn't
    " work; I'm not sure why.
    normal k$
    " Find the next occurence of the variable
    exec '/\<' . @a . '\>'
    " Replace that occurence with the text we yanked
    exec ':.s/\<' . @a . '\>/' . @b
    :let @a = l:tmp_a
    :let @b = l:tmp_b
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>ri :call InlineVariable()<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" MAPS TO JUMP TO SPECIFIC COMMAND-T TARGETS AND FILES
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
map <leader>gr :topleft :split config/routes.rb<cr>
function! ShowRoutes()
  " Requires 'scratch' plugin
  :topleft 100 :split __Routes__
  " Make sure Vim doesn't write __Routes__ as a file
  :set buftype=nofile
  " Delete everything
  :normal 1GdG
  " Put routes output in buffer
  :0r! rake -s routes
  " Size window to number of lines (1 plus rake output length)
  :exec ":normal " . line("$") . _ "
  " Move cursor to bottom
  :normal 1GG
  " Delete empty trailing line
  :normal dd
endfunction
map <leader>gR :call ShowRoutes()<cr>
map <leader>gv :CtrlPClearCache<cr>\|:CtrlP app/views<cr>
map <leader>gc :CtrlPClearCache<cr>\|:CtrlP app/controllers<cr>
map <leader>gm :CtrlPClearCache<cr>\|:CtrlP app/models<cr>
map <leader>gh :CtrlPClearCache<cr>\|:CtrlP app/helpers<cr>
map <leader>gl :CtrlPClearCache<cr>\|:CtrlP lib<cr>
map <leader>gp :CtrlPClearCache<cr>\|:CtrlP public<cr>
map <leader>gs :CtrlPClearCache<cr>\|:CtrlP spec<cr>
map <leader>gf :CtrlPClearCache<cr>\|:CtrlP features<cr>
map <leader>gg :topleft 100 :split Gemfile<cr>
map <leader>gt :CtrlPClearCache<cr>\|:CtrlPTag<cr>
map <leader>f :CtrlPClearCache<cr>\|:CtrlP<cr>
map <leader>F :CtrlPClearCache<cr>\|:CtrlP %%<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" SWITCH BETWEEN TEST AND PRODUCTION CODE
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! OpenTestAlternate()
  let new_file = AlternateForCurrentFile()
  exec ':e ' . new_file
endfunction
function! AlternateForCurrentFile()
  let current_file = expand("%")
  let new_file = current_file
  let in_spec = match(current_file, '^spec/') != -1
  let going_to_spec = !in_spec
  let in_app = match(current_file, '\<controllers\>') != -1 || match(current_file, '\<models\>') != -1 || match(current_file, '\<views\>') != -1
  if going_to_spec
    if in_app
      let new_file = substitute(new_file, '^app/', '', '')
    end
    let new_file = substitute(new_file, '\.rb$', '_spec.rb', '')
    let new_file = 'spec/' . new_file
  else
    let new_file = substitute(new_file, '_spec\.rb$', '.rb', '')
    let new_file = substitute(new_file, '^spec/', '', '')
    if in_app
      let new_file = 'app/' . new_file
    end
  endif
  return new_file
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>. :call OpenTestAlternate()<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" RUNNING TESTS
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! RunTests(filename)
    " Write the file and run tests for the given filename
    :w
    :silent !echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo
    :silent !echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo
    :silent !echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo
    :silent !echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo
    :silent !echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo
    :silent !echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo;echo
    if match(a:filename, '\.feature$') != -1
        exec ":!script/features " . a:filename
    else
        if filereadable("script/test")
            exec ":!script/test " . a:filename
        elseif filereadable("Gemfile")
            exec ":!bundle exec rspec --color " . a:filename
        else
            exec ":!rspec --color " . a:filename
        end
    end
endfunction

function! SetTestFile()
    " Set the spec file that tests will be run for.
    let t:grb_test_file=@%
endfunction

function! SetLineNumber()
    " set the spec file that tests will be run for.
    let t:spec_line_number=line('.')
endfunction

function! RunTestFileWithBacktrace(...)
    if a:0
        let command_suffix = a:1
    else
        let command_suffix = ""
    endif

    " Run the tests for the previously-marked file.
    let in_test_file = match(expand("%"), '\(.feature\|_spec.rb\)$') != -1
    if in_test_file
        call SetTestFile()
    elseif !exists("t:grb_test_file")
        return
    end
    call RunTests(t:grb_test_file . command_suffix . " -b")
endfunction

function! RunTestFile(...)
    if a:0
        let command_suffix = a:1
    else
        let command_suffix = ""
    endif

    " Run the tests for the previously-marked file.
    let in_test_file = match(expand("%"), '\(.feature\|_spec.rb\)$') != -1
    if in_test_file
        call SetTestFile()
    elseif !exists("t:grb_test_file")
        return
    end
    call RunTests(t:grb_test_file . command_suffix)
endfunction

function! RunNearestTest()
    let in_test_file = match(expand("%"), '\(.feature\|_spec.rb\)$') != -1
    if in_test_file 
        call SetLineNumber()
    end
    call RunTestFile(":" . t:spec_line_number ) 
endfunction

function! RunNearestTestWithBacktrace()
    let spec_line_number = line('.')
    call RunTestFile(":" . spec_line_number ) 
endfunction

map <leader>T :call RunTestFile()<cr>
map <leader>t :call RunNearestTest()<cr>
map <leader>B :call RunTestFileWithBacktrace()<cr>
map <leader>b :call RunNearestTestWithBacktrace()<cr>
map <leader>a :call RunTests('')<cr>
map <leader>c :w\|:!script/features<cr>
map <leader>w :w\|:!script/features --profile wip<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Md5 COMMAND
" Show the MD5 of the current buffer
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
command! -range Md5 :echo system('echo '.shellescape(join(getline(<line1>, <line2>), '\n')) . '| md5')

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" OpenChangedFiles COMMAND
" Open a split for each dirty file in git
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! OpenChangedFiles()
  only " Close all windows, unless they're modified
  let status = system('git status -s | grep "^ \?\(M\|A\)" | cut -d " " -f 3')
  let filenames = split(status, "\n")
  exec "edit " . filenames[0]
  for filename in filenames[1:]
    exec "sp " . filename
  endfor
endfunction
command! OpenChangedFiles :call OpenChangedFiles()

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" InsertTime COMMAND
" Insert the current time
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
command! InsertTime :normal a<c-r>=strftime('%F %H:%M:%S.0 %z')<cr>
```

And this is my vim version :

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled May  5 2012 20:53:55)
Included patches: 1-154
Compiled by dougui@osacar
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
+conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs 
-dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path 
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() -gettext -hangul_input +iconv 
+insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent 
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape 
+mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse 
+mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg -osfiletype 
+path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer +profile -python 
-python3 +quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent 
-sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
 -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp
 -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim       -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -ldl        -lruby1.8 -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have ctags installed? and have restarted vim?

Comment: I did this : sudo apt-get install exuberant-ctags and its installed successfully. I restarted vim also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I apologize. It was just a problem with my key board. With my french canadian configuration I must to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt Car</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>. I will map this keys.

Comment: That's OK, it might help someone else with the same kind of issue.

Comment: I put map <leader>¸ <c-]> in my .vimrc file. It's simpler.

Comment: That's not as bad as me spending twenty minutes searching for answers only to discover I was pressing Ctrl + [ the whole time...

Answer (score 2):

Some simple tests :

- To use tags, you must first generate a tag file (which index all the symbols). This is done by executing `ctags -R .` from the command line or `:!ctags -R .`from Vim.
- After you have executed the command, check that a `tag` file has been created in the directory. This is a test file, so you can check if the list of symbols looks sensible.
- Lastly, you can only jump on a tag, if Vim find the `tag` file in the path. This is achieve by setting the `tags` option in your .vimrc

I use the following option:

```
" search first in current directory then file directory for tag file
set tags=tags,../tags
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The tag file is create but I have the same problem.

Comment: set tags=tags,./tags should be set tags=tags,../tags (extra dot).  Edit won't let me add one character, so I had to leave a comment.

Comment: It might also be helpful for others when diagnosing this sort of thing to inspect the output of `:echo tagfiles()`, at least to make sure it's finding the tag file(s) you think it should be.

Comment: @equant: I finally noticed your comment and updated the path as per your suggestion